# New to Blender Unable to create an A Frame Building

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender and to this whole 3D world.

I want to build something simple first. And I saw an A-frame cabin video named "[How to model a low-poly a-frame cabin in Blender | Blender 2.7 Beginner's Tutorial](https://youtu.be/k4luR3_qQFc)".

I have a mountain scene on my layout with many Pine trees already there.   And a nice 1:87 scale A-Frame cabin would look perfect there that I can 3D print.

So when watching the video I saw how to add a plane: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for *Add Plane*

I made a ground, 100 on X-axis and 100 on Y-axis which I have no problem with.

I then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for *Add Cube*, <kbd>N</kbd> for properties: X: 6.5 m, Y: 6.5 m, Z 6.5 m.

But then I get lost. How did you make the A-Frame?

I played back the video about 50 times and do not hear how and when to use Hot Keys. They are hard to see without seeing the keyboard.

So what Hot Keys do you use to create the A-Frame?

Comment: Hello and welcome, Tom! I got lost, too. It's hard to answer your question when you talk about a video that only you have seen ;-) Post the link to video or add a screenshot.

Comment: Blender is not great for the kind of CAD design you want to do.  I'd suggest one of the free CAD programs instead.  I suspect you meant [this video](https://youtu.be/k4luR3_qQFc) but it's for an old version of Blender so you will get lost.

Comment: Thanks guys for your  response    I have made some progress but stuck on step 8 of the video that Marty posted.  On her video I see the XYZ Axis arrows on my cube I do not see them I do at the first 4 steps as soon as I hit TAB to go into Edit mode they disappear.  How do I get them on my view?

Comment: Hello! Feel free to edit your question and add details. The A-frame is created by scaling the top face of the cube along the X-axis. In *Edit* mode press *1,2*, and *3* for the *Vertex*, *Edge*, and *Face* selection modes. Press *T* to see the toolbar. There you can activate the gizmo. (the XYZ Axis arrow thingy). Widen the icons to see their labels. Shortcuts: E=extrude (1:44 in the video), Ctrl+R = add edge loops (2:44), I = inset selected faces (6:43).

Comment: Hello  Yes I am making progress I have the A-Frame made now.  But I am having issue moving the object so I can select both sides and the top of the roof.   When I place my mouse pointer near the object and click on "G" it just moves the entire object  I currently see the face of the A-Frame   I hover over the object select "L"  then I select "G" but the entire object moves around I need the object to show the top and right side then move the object to show the other side of the roof.   How do I do that?   Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Are you in *Edit* mode? Blender is very context-sensitive. It matters which object you have selected, which the active object is, in which editor mode you are, and even where your mouse pointer is. Grant Abbitt has updated his tutorial for complete beginners. Maybe you want to check it out here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnj2BL4chaQ&list=PLn3ukorJv4vuU3ILv3g3xnUyEGOQR-D8J

Answer (score 0):

Creating an A-frame house is not hard when you are familiar with the *Extrude*, *Inset*, and *Add Edge Loop* operations.

Start with the default cube. Then switch to *Edit* mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get a pie menu).

In *Edit* mode, make the toolbar visible (<kbd>T</kbd>) if it's not here. You can drag the toolbar larger to see the labels. Tooltips show you the keyboard shortcuts.

Press <kbd>3</kbd> for *Face Selection* mode, then select the top face of the cube. Select the *Scale* tool and scale down the face along the X-axis and you will have the A shape. Alternately, you can press <kbd>S</kbd> for scale and then <kbd>X</kbd> to restrict it to the X-axis. Move the mouse to scale. If it overlaps you need to move the mouse away first to have a wider range. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or left mouse button (LMB) to confirm, RGB or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel.

[image: screenshot A]

Then you can select the *Extrude* tool, and select the left, top, and right faces (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+left click) of the cube. Extrude them up to create the roof. Select the front faces of the roof and extrude them along the Y-axis to have the roof overhang a bit.

After the extrusion of the roof, you can adjust the thickness when you move first the left and then the right faces of the roof along the *Normal* direction. For this, you can switch the *Transformation orientation* to *Normal*. Don't forget to switch it back to *Global* when you're done.

In the *Adjust Last Operation* popup (<kbd>F9</kbd>) at the bottom left, you can adjust the settings of the last operation. This is useful to give both sides of the roof the same thickness. Just copy & paste the value for Z.

*Tip*: when you cancel the extrusion you can get sometimes duplicated vertices. This can cause problems later. To get rid of them you can *Merge* them *By Distance* with <kbd>M</kbd>.

[image: screenshot A2]

To follow the next steps of the tutorial select the *Vertex Selection* mode <kbd>1</kbd>. Then you can select vertices and add edge loops with the tool or <kbd>R</kbd>. To change the number of loops use the mouse wheel or <kbd>Numbpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Numbpad -</kbd>. In the popup *Adjust Last Operation* you can also change it afterwards.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> toggles X-ray and wireframe shading (<kbd>Z</kbd>) at the same time in Blender 2.8.

For the face insets select *Face Selection* mode <kbd>3</kbd> again.

Comment: I now have the Aframe made and  exported it to an STL file and sent it to my friend with a 3D printer.   It came out great except for one thing it was a solid piece.   This is for my Model railroad and I would like to add lighting to the inside of the building.    How can I remove the inside of the cabin   If I place the object in Edit Mode and do a CTRL 7 to turn the object upside down so I see the bottom  AND THEN extrude OUT  THE INSIDE  but not sure about how to accomplish this  any ideas?   Thanks

Comment: Congratulations! :-) Yes, if you want to make the inner part of the cabin hollow just do it the way you described. Go to the bottom view and select the bottom face, then inset the face (key I) and create the thickness for the walls. Now select the newly created center face and extrude it (key E) in the direction of the roof along the Z-axis.  This creates the inner room. It's cubic, but just scale it down along the X-axis as you did with the top face in the very first step. And it created the inner A shape. Done :-)